# How do I install a current version of OpenGL for Windows C++?

Tags: c++, windows, api, opengl

I'm running Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010. The version of OpenGL included (#include ) is version 1.1, and I'd like to be working with a reasonably current version -- some sort of version 3 or 4.

What do I need to do in order to get to that state? The OpenGL SDK page at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/ seems to say that you're not allowed to download the SDK, and the OpenGL wiki at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started says that you're expected to already have it, and if you don't have it, it points you to sites where you can download graphics-card manufacturers' DLLs. But surely I don't need to build a different version of the game I'm working on for each graphics card I'm going to be working with.

StackOverflow also doesn't seem to have anything, at least not phrased in a way that I can follow. I just want a download link to an installer that I can run, which will leave me with a reasonably up-to-date OpenGL API... Where do I go to get it?

**Update:** OpenGL appears to have an ideosyncratic idiom of some sort which doesn't involve having an SDK -- i.e., a package of .DLL, .lib, and headers. I'm using DirectX, which does. (In fact, the DirectX SDK even includes documentation!)

Comment: "*you're not allowed to download the SDK*" That's because it's not an SDK. They call it an "SDK" because they wanted to sucker people into thinking that OpenGL had a real, officially supported SDK. It's just a (poorly updated) grab-bag of libraries that the website maintainer sticks links onto. The Getting started page on the wiki explains exactly how this works. If you want OpenGL applications to work on someone else's system, then *they* will also need to have installed recent drivers. But that's true of any graphics application.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to make sense of. What do I need to install and #include in order to use OpenGL in an up-to-date manner? Where do I get opengl32.lib? Where do I learn what header files I'll need, and where do I get them? If it doesn't have an SDK, how do we even know what functions are in it and what they do?

Comment: An "SDK" is just a fancy name for a "library". "*Where do I get opengl32.lib?*" The Getting Started page was very clear on that: "Visual Studio, and most Windows compilers, come with this library." It was the sentence *after* the one that told you to link to it. And the part titled "Getting Functions" explains about the header situation. Please *read* the pages you've linked to; don't just scan them for certain terms or search for "download this". Actually go through and understand what it's saying.

Comment: I already did that. Read the first paragraph of my post, where I said that I have version 1.1 of OpenGL, which comes with Visual Studio, and I'm trying to get a current version.

Comment: If you did indeed read the wiki page, then you must know about OpenGL function loading and such. So you shouldn't have to ask that question.

Comment: That said, I'm looking at the "Loading Libraries" section. If I understand it rightly -- and what I'm seeing there is striking me as extremely strange -- OpenGL is a DLL and a set of pointers, and individual "loading libraries" provide their own headers and .lib files, which link into the DLL. Is this in any way accurate?

Comment: All I read of the wiki page was the section on downloading OpenGL; I assumed that that would be the section that covered installing a header and .lib file. It looks like I was mistaken. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Forget it. I'm using DirectX -- the SDK not only exists, it even comes with documentation! Compatibility with non-Windows platforms can fend for itself; I've been stalled on the cusp of graphics for long enough.

Comment: If you give up without reading the documentation carefully you don't need to wonder why you've failed. Graphics programming isn't easy and OpenGL is not making things easier. Yet if you read the DirectX documentation as you read the OpenGL docs, then you will fail there too. Have a look at [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). You will need more libraries for [matrices and vectors](http://glm.g-truc.net/) and for [window/input handling](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: Skalli: it turns out I'd confused OpenGL with SDL, which I've already learned in much greater depth. these projects need names that don't sound so similar...

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: Well, I haven't had any problems with the names of OpenGL and SDl. ;) Just a hint: if you add an @ in front of names, the users get notified about your comment. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all OpenGL is not some centrally managed library and implementation (opposed to DirectX), that's why you can't download **the** SDK, because that's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL itself is just a bunch of documents that describe an API that drivers provide and programs can use. However, the actual implementation of the API lives in the context of an operating system. And that makes things a little bit difficult if you want your API to be independent of an OS. DirectX has it easy, because it's designed for only one particular OS. That OS is Windows and that means DirectX can be written against parts of the underlying OS. Which makes development of an SDK manageable.

So what does OpenGL do then? Well, it requires that some part of the OS will be so generous and make it available to the program. In the most simple form (and in hindsight this would have been the better option, because it would save so many questions like yours) this interface would have provided exactly one function: `GetProcAddress`. For each and every function found in the OpenGL spec you could have got a pointer to the actual thing in your OpenGL driver by that function. But, lazy as most programmers are they went the easy way and said: *"Oh well, the current spec of OpenGL it at version 1.1, how about we expose all of OpenGL-1.1 on the interfacing library's surface. And everything that comes after we expose through extensions that are to be loaded by `GetProcAddress`; after all, how much new functionality will there be…"*. Turns out: A lot.

Anyway, every compiler offering support for an OS is supposed to provide interface libraries for every API the OS ships with. Which for Windows is OpenGL-1.1. If you want an actual version bump on the OpenGL interface library, that would mean an OS update. But that's not so different from DirectX, where new DirectX versions are shipping with OS updates. It's just that Microsoft doesn't see a reason to support OpenGL. So OpenGL-1.1 is what's visible on the surface and we have to deal with it. And since it's included in what compilers ship there's no reason for providing an actual SDK to download, because everything necessary is already right there on your compiler installation.

Okay, so how to get those functions from *later* versions of OpenGL then? Well: `GetProcAddress`. That's the official way to do it. And because the actual details depend on the OS in question, but OpenGL is OS independent there simply can not be a **definitive** OpenGL SDK. So officially what you have to do is:

- Download the OpenGL headers for later versions from http://opengl.org/registry
- For each function you want to use define a function pointer variable to hold it
- Load the function pointer using `GetProcAddress`

Of course if you just want to use modern OpenGL this is rather tedious. So some people developed 3rd party tools that do the deed for you. And for everything that concerns you as programmer, these tools behave very much like an SDK. The most popular choice so far (but unfortunately it's not completely trouble free, with regard of the bleeding edge of OpenGL) is GLEW. Using GLEW is quite easy. I recommend using it statically linked:

1. Download GLEW from http://glew.sourceforge.net
2. Place glew.c and glew.h alongside your projects source files.
3. Add glew.c to the list of compiled sources; make sure to have the `GLEW_STATIC` preprocessor macro definition be configured into your projects global compiler flags.
4. Use `#include "glew.h"` instead of `#include <GL/gl.h>`
5. Right after you created an OpenGL window in your program call `glewInit()`

Now some advice: You should really learn to **read** documentation (not just skim it). All of what I've just written is stated on the very references you linked.

Comment: Nice answer but " I recommend using it statically linked" - why ?

Comment: If they want their wiki to be read like Shakespeare, they should write it like Shakespeare; I tried to read through, got stuck on strange disclaimers using undefined terms, and gave up. But thank you for explaining what on Earth was going on there -- the background that you provide here was not on the wiki, at least not in a form recognizable to a non-initiate who naively assumed that an API would exist.  From further discussion, though, I've figured out that OpenGL isn't what I was looking for; in fact, I had confused it with SDL.

Answer (score 8):

Let me answer by quoting the link you  provided

> For most libraries you are familiar with, you simply #include a header file, make sure a library is linked into your project or makefile, and it all works. OpenGL doesn't work that way.
>   For reasons that are ultimately irrelevant to this discussion, you must manually load functions via a platform-specific API call. **This boilerplate work is done with various OpenGL loading libraries; these make this process smooth. You are strongly advised to use one**.

this passage contains a handy link to a wiki page entitled [OpenGL Loading Library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)

Answer (score 4):

As so far as I can tell with working in the OpenTK framework(C#) and the JOGL framework(Java), your OpenGL version is determined by your graphics card. I know my laptop only supports OpenGL 1.1 on my desktop it supports the most recent version.

Laptop has an Intel IGP with an I5 proc.

Desktop has a Radeon 6950HD.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what I do in order to #include a version of <gl.h> that's more current than 1.1...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought that you were worried about it because the framework was reporting it was running in gl 1.1 not that the library didn't have the >1.1 functions. Depending on what you need it for you may want to consider a wrapper that creates a window with the openGL context for you. FreeGlut comes to mind. http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I wanted to get a current version of the header files and library for OpenGL. But I'm giving up on that; if it's this hard to do it, I can only imagine what working with the actual library will be like.