# c++ fatal error: glad/gl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, ubuntu-18.04, glfw

I want to make a simple game using C++ & [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/).

I included the library using CMake as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDART 20)

project(tetris_game)

SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(PkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(opengl REQUIRED gl)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3)

add_executable(tetris ./src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(tetris ${opengl_LIBRARIES} glfw)
target_include_directories(tetris PUBLIC ${opengl_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(tetris PUBLIC ${opengl_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

Without the `glad/gl.h` header file, OpenGL works fine. I successfully open a window using OpenGL, but when I include that header, the error occurs:

> fatal error: glad/gl.h: No such file or directory

My directory structure as follows:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── builds
├   ├── more files.
├
├-- libs
├   ├-- glfw3
├   ├   ├-- deps
├   ├   ├   ├-- glad
├   ├   ├   ├   ├-- gl.h
├   ├   ├   ├
├   ├   ├   ├-- glad_gl.c

...
```

I tried this solution:

instead of

```
add_executable(tetris ./src/main.cpp)
```

I use

```
add_executable(tetris ./src/main.cpp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3/deps/glad/gl.h ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3/deps/glad_gl.c)
```

but did not work.

Comment: as I said above, I'm beginner and I follow tutorials and I use this one [link](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html). They use `glad/gl.h`

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I did not see any file named as `glad.h` in `glfw3` library. I will find the file and use in project.

Comment: You could try adding `${glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to your `target_include_directories()` command in your CMake file.

Comment: `target_include_directories(tetris PUBLIC ${glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${opengl_INCLUDE_DIRS})` did not work. thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Acutally, per the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html), `target_include_directories()` should only have `${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}`, not `${opengl_INCLUDE_DIRS}`. Have you tried this?

Comment: I changed all opengl text to uppercase. It's same did not work.

Comment: What tutorial did you use to construct your CMake file? The one I linked, which is the latest GLFW build gude, seems to be using different GLFW and OpenGL variable names.

Comment: I did not use any tutorial to construct CMake. I tried to use tutorial instructions for CMake but I did not successfully open a window so I just search on google.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest modifying your CMake file to use the `find_package()`, `target_link_libraries()`, and `target_include_directories()` calls as described in the [documentation here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_source). The other examples you may have found online may have been out-dated, and the variables to use may have changed...

Comment: ...why are you trying to `#include` GLFW's private GLAD copy?  Use [your own](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base).

Comment: I understand what you mean. When I learn, I will apply your suggestion. ^^

Comment: your solution worked thank you @genpfault

Comment: `CMAKE_CXX_STANDART` should have `D` at the end: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html

Comment: **I Think This Link gives an idea to you.** [Link..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957325/how-do-i-install-a-current-version-of-opengl-for-windows-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this two lines to CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3/deps/)
add_executable(tetris ./src/main.cpp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3/deps/glad_gl.c)
```

Now, OpenGL is working.

Comment: How did you get `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw3` ? Is that something you must include in your project? Is it a git submodule?